# Can I just claim this arrow exists in this specific case of the Yoneda lemma?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

From Mac Lane's Category Theory:

> For objects $r,s \in D$, each natural transformation $D(r, -) \rightarrow D(s, -)$ has the form $D(h, -)$ for a unique arrow $h:s \rightarrow r$.

I can see by the Yoneda lemma that letting $y : \text{Nat}(D(r, -), D(s, -) \cong D(s,r)$ by $\alpha : D(r, -) \rightarrow D(s,-) \mapsto \alpha_r1_r$, we get $\alpha_r1_r $ is an element of $D(s,r)$.

Does it makes sense to just say: Let $h=\alpha_r1_r$ and therefore $D(h, -): D(r, -) \rightarrow D(s, -)$ is the required natural transformation between functors?

Comment: There's no "therefore" there. One needs to **prove** that your natural transformation is $D(h,-)$ by using the definition of naturality.

Comment: Can you explain how $D(h, -)$ is a natural transformation?  I can see that $\alpha$ is natural and $D(\alpha_r 1_r, -)$ has the same diagram as $\alpha$ and veritcal hom functors, but I don't understand how I'd show the equality.

Comment: If $h:r\to s$, then $D(h,-):D(s,-)\to D(r,-)$, in that, for an object $x$, we have $D(h,x):D(s,x)\to D(r,x)$, and an arrow is mapped to a commuting square.